# How to output for each loop values in array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have got the following for each loop

```
 foreach ($jcart->get_contents() as $item) {  
  $reg1['items'][] = array(
    'description' => urlencode($item['name']),
    'amount' => urlencode($item['price']),
    'quantity' => urlencode($item['qty'])
  );
}
```

Which out puts fine:

"items":[{"description":"Product1","amount":"519","quantity":"1"},{"description":"Product2","amount":"339","quantity":"1"}]}

However when I do the following it only gets the last item

```
$req = array( 
    array(
'action' => 'SALE',
'type' => 1,
'countryCode' => 826,
'currencyCode' => 826),
 
    'items' => array(
    'description' => urlencode($item['name']),
    'amount' => urlencode($item['price']),
    'quantity' => urlencode($item['qty'])
        )
);
```

the out put is:

array(2) { [0]=> array(9) { ["action"]=> string(4) "SALE" ["type"]=> int(1) ["countryCode"]=> int(826) ["currencyCode"]=> int(826) ["items"]=> array(3) { ["description"]=> string(37) "Product2" ["amount"]=> string(3) "339" ["quantity"]=> string(1) "1" } }

How do it get all products in this array?
Any help welcome

Comment: _"However when I do the following"_ - do _what_, exactly? You have shown us the definition of an array with _one_ item in the `items` array. Is that supposed to be your input data now, that takes the place of `$jcart->get_contents()`, or ... what?

Comment: @CBroe I am ever to sorry if it is very obvios what to do, howver I just wanted to show that the for each loop works I need it to work inside the array,I just dont know how to get it to work

Comment: It is anything but obvious to me what to do - because what your actual _problem_ is, is currently very unclear.

Comment: @Cbroe I want to repeat the results from the for each loop into the array to that both items product 1 and product 2 will be put it in the $req

Comment: But that _already_ happened with your first code snippet, no? So why do you need to change anything about that now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to declare a portion of the array statically and then add more items to it?

If so, then the solution is to do exactly that - declare the static portion separartely first and then use your loop to add more things to it. You don't have to declare an entire array in a single statement.

```
//declare the static portion of the array
$req = array( 
    array(
     'action' => 'SALE',
     'type' => 1,
     'countryCode' => 826,
     'currencyCode' => 826
    ),
    'items' => array()
);

//now add the rest of the data using a loop
foreach ($jcart->get_contents() as $item) {  
  $req['items'][] = array(
    'description' => urlencode($item['name']),
    'amount' => urlencode($item['price']),
    'quantity' => urlencode($item['qty'])
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however this will result in NULL

Comment: No it won't. What is your evidence for that?

Comment: Sorry I missed something out it was correct. Thanks for you help